# Transferring data from one ESP Project to another in SAS Viya 4.0. Azure Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, lua, sas

I am working on a project where I want to have two ESP Projects in SAS Viya 4.0 communicate with eachother. The plan is to have one ESP project running with a source window set up as a kafka consumer listening to a Kafka queue. Then I want the other, separate, ESP project to be able to access the same data that the consuming source window in the first ESP project. I have tried tinkering around with different connectors and adapters to connect directly to the source window of the first project, however, this is proving difficult as I do not have information about the address space that each project is running in. Is there any "built-in" way of connecting two such source windows from different projects together? I have been looking at Lua-connectors to achieve this, but from what I've understood, Lua-connectors instantiated inside an ESP-project are only accessible by windows and Lua-connectors inside this same project. The whole problem here stems from the fact that the working environment is very containerized, making addressing difficult.

Tried connecting directly to the local address of the kubernetes pod and then going to the path of the source window without luck. Tried a localhost approach as well. Checked standard ports 443, 31415 and 31416 for SAS Viya HTTP and pubsub capabilities.

See picture below for beautiful illustration of the problem.